# How can I use wget to send POST data?

Tags: linux, bash, http, wget

I want to make following POST request to my server using wget:

```
email=abc@abc.com&file1=@FILE_HERE&file2=@FILE_HERE
```

In the above request, there are three POST parameters called `email` , `file1` and `file2` where `email` contains email of user and `file1` , `file2` contain a file.

How can I send it using `wget`? I don't want to use `curl`.

Answer (score 17):

Use the `--post-data` parameter.

So your command will end with:

```
--post-data "email=abc@abc.com&file1=@FILE_HERE&file2=@FILE_HERE"
```

Answer (score 4):

Another method is to put your data in a file. For example, if you saved a file called `params.txt` as:

```
email=abc@abc.com
file1=@FILE_HERE
file2=@FILE_HERE
```

You could use `--post-file params.txt`